# Git - Pushing local branch to remote and making local branch track that remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I recently started using the GIT command line commands ( I used to use SourceTree).

When I want to create a new branch, I would usually do `git checkout -b <branch-name>`.
When I want to push it to remote, I would do `git push origin <branch-name>`.

Now after I have pushed this local branch to remote, how do I make my local branch track this remote branch? ( I do not want my local branch to track master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `-u`:

```
$ git push -u origin localname:remotename


$ git help push
...  
 -u, --set-upstream
       For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
       upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1)
       and other commands. For more information, see branch.<name>.merge
       in git-config(1).
```